# Extract number from a text after symbol "X"

Tags: regex

I have the following text in a column, where I need to extract number next to second "X" or "x",

in the below text, it is `54`.

```
40sHT + 2/20sCMD X 30sHT + 2/20sCMD 56 X 54 54" AWM/C129-DOBY
```

Some other sample texts:

```
21sOE X 12sFL 56 X 36 63" PLAIN          # Result must be : 36

40sC X 40sC_100 X 91_63" PLAIN           # Result: 91

16sOE x 12sLY 84 x 48 71" 3/1 DRILL      # Result: 48
```

Comment: Maybe `[Xx]\s?(\d+)(?:.(?![Xx]))*$`

Answer (score 0):

**Given:**

```
40sHT + 2/20sCMD X 30sHT + 2/20sCMD 56 X 54 54" AWM/C129-DOBY   # Result: 54

21sOE X 12sFL 56 X 36 63" PLAIN                                 # Result: 36

40sC X 40sC_100 X 91_63" PLAIN                                  # Result: 91

16sOE x 12sLY 84 x 48 71" 3/1 DRILL                             # Result: 48
```

**Use:**

```
[Xx]\s?(\d+)(?:.(?![Xx]))*$
```

**Demo and Explanation:**

- https://regex101.com/r/KshMUE/1

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state which tool/language this is using, so it's hard to know for sure what to suggest.

However, if possible, I would consider splitting the string on the letter `"x"` (or `"X"`) as this makes the regex part much easier to follow. For example, something like:

```
input = '40sHT + 2/20sCMD X 30sHT + 2/20sCMD 56 X 54 54" AWM/C129-DOBY'
input.split(/x/i)[2][/\d+/]
```

By doing this split, we first extract only the desired section of the string (in this case, `' 54 54" AWM/C129-DOBY'`), so the regex (`/\d+/`) becomes trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?i)(?<=x[^x]{1,100}x.)\d+
```

- `(?i)`: case-insensitive
- `(?<=`: start of positive look-behind
- `x[^x]{1,100}x.`: an `x`followed by up to 100 any characters except `x`, followed by `x` and any one single character
- `)`: end of look-behind
- `\\d+`: one or more digits